# Mixing class and function generics in Kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin

I'm trying to create an interface that defines a single method. The type of the argument for that method must be a type parameter of the interface, because implementations of the interface will have unique implementations for this parameter. Fine so far, but the catch is that the parameter also has a type argument that is tied to the method. Can I have a parameter of a type defined as a class type argument, which also has its own type argument that's tied to the method?

Put another way:

I am trying to build an api client interface with two implementations. Each client makes api calls based on `Request<T>` objects that are passed into their `rxecute` functions (RxJava + execute, and yes, I am unduly proud of the name).

My issue is with how to define the `rxecute` method in the interface. Let me lay out some sample code (my actual code isn't using `impl`, don't worry).

```
interface Request<T> // T is return type of the request

class RequestImpl<T>: Request<T> { // impl }

interface ApiClient<R : Request<*>> {
  // R should somehow be of type Request<T>
  fun <T> rxecute(request: R): Single<T>
}

class ApiClientImpl : ApiClient<RequestImpl<????>> {
  override fun <T> rxecute(request: RequestImpl<T>): Single<T> = // impl
}
```

I would like to be able to use it like this:

```
val apiClient = ApiClientImpl()
apiClient.rxecute(RequestImpl<SomeClass>()).subscribe(someClassResult -> ...)
```

Is it possible to create an interface like this or do generics not work like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Kotlin generics cannot be manipulated in that way; a type parameter `R` cannot be used as a generic type itself (`R<T>`), and its upper bound is fixed at the declaration site, and you can only use a type parameter `R` as a single upper bound (no way to add another one, `where Q : R, Q : Request<T>` doesn't work).

You can only parameterize concrete types, and one option that comes to my mind is [recursive generics](https://www.sitepoint.com/self-types-with-javas-generics/) pattern (it is also used with Java). You can add another type parameter for the implementation type to `Request`, so that it becomes `interface Request<R, T>`. This requires you to add the types of the implementations to the inherited type declarations:

```
class RequestImpl<T>: Request<RequestImpl<*>, T> { /* impl */ }
```

Then modify `ApiClient`:

```
interface ApiClient<R : Request<R, *>> {
    fun <T> rxecute(request: Request<R, T>): Single<T>
}
```

<sup>An unwelcome side-effect that arises here is that you need to cast the `request` to use it as a `RequestImpl`: `request as RequestImpl`.</sup>

And transform `ApiClientImpl` as follows:

```
class ApiClientImpl : ApiClient<RequestImpl<*>> {
    override fun <T> rxecute(request: Request<RequestImpl<*>, T>): Single<T> = TODO()
}
```

This solution looks much more verbose than what you asked for, but recursive generics seem to be a common workaround for such cases, which require a stronger type system than what Java and Kotlin can offer.

---

[<sup>(runnable demo of the code in the answer)</sup>](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/t49qq9agrvr2gi9v1ari6apd6n/p0i2hflpn6ngn9hifklvlrdhtb)

Comment: I haven't seen recursive generics before, but that's absolutely badshit. What's more, it compiles. I need to fix some other code before I can run the whole thing, but it seems good.
Minor detail; you also need to cast `(request as RequestImpl<T>)` now, which is a little ugly but is safe. 
I'll mark this as answered as soon as I fix my stuff and confirm it's working.

Comment: @DavidWhitman, yep, `request as RequestImpl<T>` is a known pain in the neck when using recursive generics. You can shorten it a bit without losing type safety: `request as RequestImpl` (`<T>` is not checked at runtime anyway, and if it matches at compile-time then it's still safe)

Comment: Stellar answer, code is working perfectly. Kotlin is a beautiful language, especially when set against Java; thank you so much for your work on it.

There was one remaining bit of weirdness that I have a workaround for but others may want to be aware of. I created a wrapper for `ApiClient` with the signature `class ApiClientWrapper<out C : ApiClient<R>, R : Request<R, *>>`. It wraps the `rxecute` call using `fun <T> rxecute(request: R): Single<T>`, *but* you need to do an unsafe cast to map your results to `T` ( `.map { it as T }` ) because `request: R` has a type param of `Any?`.